# Why did Tyuule feel sad?

Tags: gate

In the final episode Tyuule said to herself that she did what she did to get revenge for her fallen country. But what was that made her sad? The actions that she took, or that she fell in love with the prince Zolzal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit late, but it's because all revenge does is leave empty. So even through Tyuule got what she wanted, she can't feel happy about any of it. They mention it earlier back with Tuka's mental issues and the fire dragon.
Oh and she doesn't love him. Can never love him for all he's done.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what Tyuule wanted was **total destruction and disintegration** of the Empire, as she blames the Empire for destruction of her homeland, and the hatred the warrior bunnies now have for her. However, due to Itami's interference, all that happens is that Zorzal is peacefully overthrown and Pīna is able to return as the Princess, the Empire remaining intact, and now with a Japanese Alliance. Therefore, her unhappiness probably stems from only being able to throw the Empire into a civil war, which Pīna will easily win with the help of Japan, but not being able to see her die at excecution and see Zorzal become a POW(Prisoner Of War) or see him capitulate at all.

Comment: Very interesting take on that!